# R6 inherit does not carry information of the inherited class when used in a function

Tags: r, r6

See example code:

```
myfunc <- function(inherit) {
  return(R6::R6Class("Derived", inherit = inherit)) 
}

Base <- R6::R6Class("Base")
Derived <- R6::R6Class("Derived", inherit = Base)
Derived2 <- myfunc(Base)
print(Derived)
print(Derived2)
```

Despite being technically equivalent, the first print statement reports:

```
<Derived> object generator
  Inherits from: <Base>
  Public:
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
  Parent env: <environment: 0x7fdf63a6cf18>
  Locked objects: TRUE
  Locked class: FALSE
  Portable: TRUE
```

While the second reports:

```
<Derived> object generator
  Inherits from: <inherit>
  Public:
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
  Parent env: <environment: 0x7fdf63afb8b8>
  Locked objects: TRUE
  Locked class: FALSE
  Portable: TRUE
```

How can I change the function myfunc so that the appropriately scoped name is used instead of the internal name inherit?

Answer (score 0):

The R6Class function uses non-standard evaluation. You could do

```
myfunc <- function(inherit) {
  eval.parent(substitute(R6::R6Class("Derived", inherit = inherit)))
}
```

to get the same output. That will resolve the `inherit` value to the value that was passed into the function

Comment: is there a way to know what uses non standard evaluation and what does not? There's no language visual or documentation information that I could infer about something being evaluated as is, or going through some form of metaprogramming

Comment: And thank you. You have been really helpful to me today.

Comment: I am having a bit of a problem, because my call is way more complex and it's also passing the parent env to the R6Class call. As a result it breaks in another way. How can I substitute only the inherit, but not the rest in the call?

Comment: There is no general way to know what uses nonstandard evaluation; there’s no documentation convention for that. I often just look at the source of the function. You can do a lot of complicated meta programming but it’s not clear what is required for your particular case. Maybe create a new question with more specifics that can be tested.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to generate a new R6 metaclass that adds shiny reactives to the resulting classes, while reusing the R6 functions. This works, but then I tried to handle inheritance as well. With inheritance, the call to the underlying R6 generator_funs$new does a get_inherit() and that fails because it's trying to look the verbatim name of the base class, but something in my code is wrong and I can't see it, in addition to the indirection inside the generator function. It's really hard for me to create something I can paste as a question. There's a lot of complexity going on.